# IEnumerable to Listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to write a method to filter a listview

```
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> CurrentList;
CurrentList = ListViewExemple.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(); 
var result = CurrentList.Select(i => i.Text.Contains(SearchTxtBox.Text));
```

Now How can i add the "result" items to a cleared  Listview

Comment: First you should change `Select()` with `Where()`. You can't do it directly with (let's say) `anotherListView.Items.AddRange(result.ToArray())` because you can't add same `ListViewItem` to two lists. You may clone them (text, subitems and appearance) or - better - do not the search on `ListViewItem` but on its _data source_ (plain C# objects you used to construct your first list). Rebuild your list every time you filter using (filtered) original data.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to keep in mind that a ListViewItem has an owner, you need to make a copy of the item to put it in another listview.  Easy to do with its Clone() method.  Or move it from one to the other, not likely in this case.  So you probably want this:

```
    var matches = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                  .Select(item => (ListViewItem)item.Clone())
                  .Where(item => item.Text.Contains(SearchTxtBox.Text));
    listView2.Items.Clear();
    listView2.Items.AddRange(matches.ToArray());
```

Comment: It does not clone the object unfortunately

Comment: No idea what "object" might mean.  It is a ListViewItem, it clones well.

Comment: as Adriano Reppetti says I've just try to clone it at the construction on and it's work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `ListView` doesn't have data binding capabilities.  So you need to add the items manually:

```
foreach (var item in result)
    someListView.Items.Add(item);
```

Or possibly:

```
someListView.Items.AddRange(result);
```

Also, you seem to have a bug here:

```
CurrentList.Select(i => i.Text.Contains(SearchTxtBox.Text))
```

This isn't going to produce a collection of `ListViewItem`s, it's going to produce a collection of `bool`s.  I think you meant this:

```
CurrentList.Where(i => i.Text.Contains(SearchTxtBox.Text))
```